# firefox ssl proxy mode

Tags: ssl, proxy

in firefox proxy setting there is 4 option to choose : http , ssl , socks , ftp
I found a lot of free server for http mode but I can not found any server that worked with ssl mode.

can someone explain about ssl mode and the ways that connect?

Answer (score 0):

The settings are a bit confusing. The proxy settings for HTTP, FTP and SSL are all used to configure a HTTP proxy which can support all these protocols, i.e. `http://`, `https://` and `ftp://` URL's. The SOCKS proxy setting is used alternatively if no such HTTP proxy is set for the relevant protocol. A SOCKS proxy can also support all of  `http://`, `https://` and `ftp://` URL's.